# call after http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

I want to use a function after i recieved data and stored it, how ever i dont get the result i want with the code i use.

Can someone provide me with some details on what i am doing wrong?

my code:

```
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'JsonLocation'
    }).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available.
            self.responseData = response.data;
        }, 
        function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log(response);
        }
    ).then(
        function completeCallback() {
            // called when the http request is finished.
            restyleData();
        }
    );
```

When the page is loaded and everything is set in place i can run the `restyleDate()` via developer options, then it works. But i just want to have it fired after everything is loaded and not do it manually.

Comment: Remove that second `.then` statement and put your `restyleData` method in your `successCallback`

Comment: so what is the specific problem with it? what does the function do? `I don't get result wanted` is not very definitive

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall the function seems to be called before all the data is on the page. I think my problem lies in the fact that the ng-repeat from angular is processed before i 'restyle'. and i need to have it after all the data is on the page.

Comment: @charlietfl I try to get a list of images (src, title, desc, ect,,,) from a json file in to an array. which should be loaded on to the page and then be styled so all margins are correct.

Comment: sounds like you need to do that in a directive and let the elements render first

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, i wrote an directive and now the page renders in the right order! Thnx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to change to:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'JsonLocation'
}).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available.
        self.responseData = response.data;
        // restyle is called after you save the result
        restyleData();
    }, 
    function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `catch` and `finally` after using then.  If you do `$scope.responseData = data`, then can use in your HTML and data will automatically populate.  So in the html it will look like `{{responseData.description}}` for instance. And if you've defined self as this then it would be: `{{self.responseData.description}}`

Alternatively, you can wrap your $http call in a function called restyleData then invoke the function (as you have) and it will display the data.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'JsonLocation'
}).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available.
        self.responseData = response.data;
    })
     .catch( 
    function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log(response);
    })
     .finally(
    function completeCallback() {
        // called when the http request is finished.
    });

restyleData();
```